# JPA2 equivalent for Hibernate collection cache?

Tags: orm, jpa-2.0

With Hibernate a collection would be cached as follows:

```
class Bar {    
  ...    
  @OneToMany
  @Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
  private Collection<Foo> foos;    
  ...
}
```

Now. I'm trying to keep this "JPA2-only". Adding the Hibernate @Cache annotation does the trick but I'm mixing JPA2 with Hibernate. Which at this level isn't that bad - but I don't want it to get worse.

Is there a JPA2-way to do this ?

Remember, this is *not* about the query cache. It's really how the JPA provider navigates through the associations. And in my case I have a very likely 1/100,000 relationship between Bar and Foo. So caching the Bar and Foo entities with @Cacheable has no effect.

Comment: Did you try the `@Cacheable` annotation (http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Cacheable.html)?

Comment: Unfortunately this is an annotation for classes. Not for variables. And this question is really about caching the relationship between two instances. Not the instances themselves.

Comment: It does seem that the JPA committee have forgotten that we need to cache associations as well as entities. Unbelievable that they missed this need.